# Python, read uart and post to MQTT, has extra spaces

Tags: python, newline, mqtt

I'm reading a string from a microcontroller to Raspberry Pi using Python.  The string looks like this:

> 5050313 9

I then split this up into MQTT topic and payload.  The value left of the " " is the topic, and the one right of " " is the payload.  My code adds extra new lines to the MQTT topic.  How can I avoid these new lines?  I've even try rstrip() on the payload.  Here's the code:

```
import serial
import time
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

def readlineCR(port):
    rv = ""
    while True:
        ch = port.read()
        rv += ch
        if ch=='\r\n' or ch=='':
                return rv


port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    rcv = port.readline()
    print(rcv)
    if len(rcv) > 4:
         mytopic, mypayload = rcv.split(" ")
         mypayload.rstrip()
         publish.single(mytopic, mypayload, hostname="localhost")
```

If I subscribe to that topic, I get this exactly:

> pi@raspberrypi:/media/pycode $ mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t
>   50C51C570B00
>
> 97
>
> 98
>
> 99

There shouldn't be any extra lines between the numbers.  It should just be

97
98
99

Any ideas where these new lines are coming from?

Comment: You're calling `port.readline()` in a loop. My guess is that you're receiving a number of lines with over `4` characters (e.g. `\r\n97\r\n`). I would inspect the number of characters read per loop iteration and then consider the approach after.

Comment: you did'nt save result of `mypayload.rstrip()` in a variable then send this variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your readlineCR shouldn't be returning rv when it gets nothing from read - it needs to never return until the complete string rv string ends with \r\n, and then it can return the rstripped string:

```
def readlineCR(port):
    rv = ""
    while True:
        ch = port.read()
        rv += ch
        if rv.endswith("\r\n"):
            return rv.rstrip()
```

In addition I don't see why you are checking the length of rcv - but it won't matter once rcv is a complete message.

Answer (score 0):

you did'nt save result of `mypayload.rstrip()` in a variable then send this variable i.e (`mpayload` not affected) look at this example:

```
>>> s='\r\n97\r\n'
>>> s.strip()
'97'
>>> s
'\r\n97\r\n'
```

the your code should be:

```
if len(rcv) > 4:
         mytopic, mypayload = rcv.split(" ")
         v=mypayload.strip()
         publish.single(mytopic, v, hostname="localhost")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(rcv)` adds a newline. To change this to a space (for example), try this:

`print(rcv, end=' ')`